# Can java annotation have complex return type like HashMap

Tags: java, collections, annotations

Can annotation have complex return type, such as HashMap.

I am looking for something like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface column {
    public HashMap<String, String> table();
}
```

so I can have a constant annotated like(**pseudo code**):

```
@column({table=(dbName, tableName), table=(dbName, tableName2)})
public static final String USER_ID = "userid";
```

If Annotation doesn't allow you to have complex return type, then any good practice for this kind of case?

Comment: excellent question..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, annotation elements can only be primitive types, Strings, `enum` types, `Class`, other annotations, or arrays of any of these.  The typical way to represent these kinds of structures would be to declare another annotation type

```
public @interface TableMapping {
  public String dbName();
  public String tableName();
}
```

then say

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface column {
    public TableMapping[] table();
}
```

And use the annotation as

```
@column(table={
  @TableMapping(dbName="dbName", tableName="tableName"),
  @TableMapping(dbName="db2", tableName="table2")
})
public String userId = "userid";
```

Comment: Don't forget enums and classes

Comment: @IanRoberts I've done something similar, it's kinda annoying, if you use @ table only, even some of the column only has one TableMapping has to have @ table along with one @ TableMapping. If you start using @ table for fields having more than one tablemapping while using @ TableMapping for the columns having only one tablemapping. But the latter case will have a more complex method for retrieving eg. getColumnsInTableA().

Answer (score 13):

A couple of years later brings us Java 8.  It offers a way to repeat annotations of the same class.

In Java 8 you can declare an annotation to be implicitly wrapped in a container annotation.  You declare as `@Repeated(value=a_class)` an annotation you want to be repeatable.  When you add multiple instances of a repeatable annotation the compiler will automatically wrap these in the container annotation `a_class` specified as argument to `@Repeated`.

If you declare:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Columns {
    Column[] value() default {};
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable( value = Columns.class )
public @interface Column {
    String dbName();
    String tableName();
}
```

then you can use the annotation multiple times with or without wrapping them in another annotation, both are equivalent:

```
@Column(dbName="db1", tableName="table1")
@Column(dbName="db2", tableName="table2")
public static final String USER_ID = "userid";

@Columns({
        @Column(dbName="db3", tableName="table3"),
        @Column(dbName="db4", tableName="table4")
})
public static final String LAST_NAME = "last name";
```

The annotations are retrieved using `getAnnotationsByType(class)` in both cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for( Field field : AnnotationsTest.class.getDeclaredFields() ){
        System.out.println("Field: " + field.getName());
        Column[] columns = field.getAnnotationsByType(Column.class);
        for( Column column : columns ){
            System.out.println("    db: " + column.dbName() + " table: " + column.tableName());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It should output:

```
Field: USER_ID
    db: db1 table: table1
    db: db2 table: table2

Field: LAST_NAME
    db: db3 table: table3
    db: db4 table: table4
```